# How to toggle back ground color on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have an Html table which I am creating using `vue.js` which is dynamic from JSON data what I am trying to do is on click I want to change background color of that row

**My code**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      billPendingData: [{
          "billno": "A1",
          "customername": "s ",
          "netamount": "131.0000",
          "billtime": "16:37:53"
        },
        {
          "billno": "A3",
          "customername": "Dheeraj ",
          "netamount": "1058.0000",
          "billtime": "17:35:12"
        }
      ],

    };
  },
  methods: {


  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="table-dark">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Bill no</th>
        <th class="text-center">C.Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Net Amt</th>
        <th class="text-center">Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="onHover" v-for="data in billPendingData" :key="data.billno" @click="rowClick(data)">
        <td>{{data.billno}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{data.customername }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{data. netamount}}</td>
        <td>{{data.billtime}}</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I just want to change the background color the row which I have clicked and if I click other one the other one should change the color

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to solve your issue

**First** declare new data model

```
data() {
    return {
       'active_row':''
    };
}
```

**Next** in your tr v-for change it to this

```
<template v-for="(data, index) in billPendingData">
    <tr :class="[(active_row == index ? 'active_row' : '') ,'onHover']" :key="data.billno" @click="rowClick(data, index)">
        <td>{{data.billno}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{data.customername }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{data. netamount}}</td>
        <td>{{data.billtime}}</td>
      </tr>
</template>
```

Next, in your method just do this

```
methods: {
   rowClick(data, index) {
      this.active_row = index
   }
}
```

**Last** in your style, you just put css on it like

```
.active_row {
   background-color:red
}
```

Comment: Hey at onClicl you are removing my method I have defined some method on that click of row

Comment: I updated my answer, I wrote like that to make your code shorter

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
<tr class="onHover" v-for="data in billPendingData" :key="data.billno" @click="rowClick(data)">
```

with next:

```
<tr class="onHover" v-for="(data, index) in billPendingData" :key="data.billno" @click="rowClick(data, index)" :class="[{'active': index === activeIndex}]">
```

Add your click handler:

```
data() {
    return {
        activeIndex: null,
...

methods: {
    rowClick(data, index){
        this.activeIndex = index;
    }

}
```

Also add appropriate highlighted css to `.active` class.

Upd.

Add to your *.vue file this code:

```
<style>
.active{
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

PS. I could make mistakes because I didn't run it on my server but you got an idea how you can do it.

Comment: Hey how could I put css style?